# jQuery focus without scroll using custom-scrollbar-plugin

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I am using custom-scrollbar-plugin

in that i need  to select the current concept without scroll (ex. is bellow the visible area)

How can I set the focus without scrollbar movement? I need to stay the scrollbar in the original place.

This is my jquery code

```
$(".content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"dark",
    advanced:{
    autoScrollOnFocus: true,
    updateOnContentResize: true
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a "}" too much in this example. Also, it is not entirely clear, what you are asking for.

Comment: thank you for reply..if i give to the current id to display the div it is displayed without scroll in front end,the same code is not working from back end..it showing error mCustomScrollbar has no method ..and ii adding the plugin.